# How to find the minimum amount of steps to come back to the starting point using four cardinal directions

Tags: python-3.x

I have done an online test and I couldn't get my head around one of the question:
Imagine to have a robot that can only move following the 4 cardinal direction North, South, West, East. Passing the commands as "N", "S", "W" or "E", every command correspond to one step. The question was about writing a function that return the minimum amount of steps necessary to return the robot to the starting position.
For example, passing the command "NW", the return value should be 2. Passing the command "NWS", return the value 1 and so on. If the robot finds itself already at the starting position the returned value would be 0 (or a string saying "starting position").

The question supposed to be for beginners but, to be honest, I'm having hard time to solve it. If anyone have any idea how to write such a program, would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about it, I didn't think of submitting this type of question on a different platform. I'll definitely keep it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate a `state-machine` using complex numbers (using the format `a+bj`, where `j` is the square root of -1).

1) Start with `start_val = 0`

2) Associate the coordinates with complex operations:

- `N` with `+1`
- `S` with `-1`
- `E` with `+j`
- `W` with `-j`

3) Then process the given string to perform the mapped operation for each character one-by-one onto `start_val`. For example:

- given the string "NW", the program would compute:

  - `start_val += 1`
  - `start_val -= j`
  - then `start_val = 1+1j`
- given the string "NWS", the program would compute:

  - `start_val += 1`
  - `start_val += j`
  - `start_val -= 1`
  - then `start_val = 0-1j`

4) After that, just **sum** the *real* part and the *imaginary* part of `start_val`. In the examples above, the result is 2 and 1, respectively. Can you see that?

I hope that can work as a solution for you.